# How do I format the results of a PHP db query before sending JSON back to application?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, json

I have a database query with several `LEFT JOIN`s.  Each time there is a different value in a related table it adds a record to the result of the SQL Query.  I'd like to manipulate the query result to format it in a way that I can use it directly in my application rather than writing logic to parse this data on the client side.

I'd like to have the output in a format that I can easily use a javascript template for displaying the data.  Right now my js is littered with HTML as I build each table individually.  If the response were formatted in a standard way I could use a template to conditionally format the results for each individual table ie **Project Basics**, **Partners**, **Contacts**.

SQL Stored Procedure:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblProjects 
LEFT JOIN  tblPartners
ON ( tblProjects.ProjectID = tblPartners.ProjectID )
LEFT JOIN tblPersons
ON ( tblProjects.ProjectID = tblPersons.ProjectID )
LEFT JOIN tblState
ON ( tblProjects.ProjectID = tblState.ProjectID )
WHERE tblProjects.ProjectID = @prjID
```

Partial SQL Output (lots of repeated information):
[image]

PHP:

```
<?php
    if (isset( $_GET["prjID"] ) ) {
        $prjID = $_GET["prjID"];
    }

    include_once("connection.php");
    $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"$dbname", "UID"=>$user, "PWD"=>$pass);
    $DBH = sqlsrv_connect($server, $connectionInfo);

    if( !$DBH ) {
        echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
    }

    $sql = "{CALL getProjectDetails(?)}";
    $params = array(&$prjID);

    if (!$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($DBH, $sql, $params) ) {
        echo "Statement could not be prepared.\n";
    }

    if ( !$query = sqlsrv_execute( $stmt ) ) {
        echo "Statement could not be executed.\n";
    }

    $result = array();
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
        # How to I format the result into objects representing each related table?
        $result[] = $row;
    }

print json_encode($result);
```

Desired Output (formatted for readability):

```
[{
    ProjectBasics: {// only send this information once instead of for every row returned
        ProjectID: 1,
        ProjectTitle: "Project Title",
        ProjectDescription: "Long description...",
        etc...
    },
    Partners: {// create an object for each partner
        {
         firstName: "John",
         lastName: "Doe",
         email: "john_doe@mail.com"
        },
        {
         firstName: "Jane",
         lastName: "Jones",
         email: "jane_jones@mail.com"
        }
    },
    States: {
        {
         Name:"Alabama",
         Abbrev: "AL"
        },
        {
         Name:"Mississippi",
         Abbrev: "MS"
        }
    }
}]
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you looked into possibly using `FOR XML` then converting that to JSON?

Comment: This is the first application I've worked on with ajax calls to a DB.  The only thing I've tried thus far is just packaging up the entire query result into an array and using `print json_encode()` to send the full result back to the application.  I'm open to any and all suggestions!

Comment: I suggest changing your stored procedure to return just the rows you need.  With select * you are returning the projectId field 4 times.  Plus, if any column names are duplicated, you will be in trouble.

Comment: I 100% agree that I can improve the stored procedure, and I plan to, but what I'm really after in this question is formatting the response so it's easier to use on the client side.  I've added a bit to the OP describing my intent to use some js templating engine to display the data.